# Openpyxl Number_Format Not Applied Until Manually Applied

Tags: python, openpyxl

**Code:**

```
def write_pandas_dataframe_to_excel(df):

  book = openpyxl.load_workbook('~/Documents/test.xlsm', read_only=False, keep_vba=True)
  sheet = book['Database']

  # Delete all rows after the header so that we can replace them with the contents of our pandas dataframe  
  sheet.delete_rows(1,sheet.max_row)
  
  #Write values from the pandas dataframe to the sheet
  for r in dataframe_to_rows(df,index=include_index, header=True):
    sheet.append(r)
  
  for row in sheet[2:sheet.max_row]: # skip the header
    cell = row[0]   # column A is a Date Field.
    cell.number_format = 'YYYY-mm-dd'
    
  book.save(excel_file_path)
  book.close()
```

**Expected Result:** I open up test.xlsm, and in column A, all dates should already be in the format YYYY-mm-dd

**Actual Result:** While the YYYY-mm-dd format gets applied without any issues when I run the python code, I then have to open up the excel file, select each cell manually and hit 'Return' in the formula window for the YYYY-mm-dd format to be applied.

Is there a way for my specified date format to be applied through the python code rather than having to manually apply it by opening up excel and selecting each cell, going to the formula bar and hitting 'Return' every time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the answer. Put simply, the date was being written to excel as a string, and that was causing the issue.

In the pandas dataframe I'm containing my data I had used strptime to format the date, which converted the date type to a generic 'object' type. I removed the strptime so that it maintained the datetime object, and that way when I write to excel it writes as a pandas Timestamp object rather than a string.